# What's the best way to generate rainbow table of md5 hashes of sprecific groupes of strings

Tags: cryptography, md5, hardware

I need a rainbow table with md5 hashes of all real numbers (with fixed amount of digits) from 1.0000000000000000 to 99.9999999999999999 and 100.0000000000000000 (10^18 hashes). How to perform it? Is there any application with this capability or the best way is to write my own in C + asm? Then how to store this data: ordinary file or database? And how long it'll take?

Comment: for personal usage ofc. I'm concerned in perfomance generally

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have no solution.

One md5 hash needs 16 bytes storage. For 10^18 hashes you need 16 x 10^18 = 1.6 x 10^19 bytes = 16 000 000 Terabytes storage. 1 TB costs at big providers about 10 $/month. In total it will cost 160 000 000 $/month.

Now calculate how many time you need to generate 10^18 hashes. Suppose you have excellent hardware that generates 10^9 hashes per second. Then you need about 10 000 days to calculate all hashes.  If you can afford 300 such CPUs, in a month you get your table. Then only pay the bill of 160 000 000 $ for storage.

Comment: Rainbow tables are significantly more compact than what your calculation suggests. The hash-chains they use trade lookup performance for storage size.

Comment: One would rather use a GPU than a CPU. For example a 1080 Ti [measured](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/973da7352f4cc005746c627527e4d073) at 31*10^9 MD5 hashes per second. Still expensive (373 GPU days), but quite a bit faster than your estimation.

Comment: It would take tens to thousands of days, 0 to thousands $, and quite a bit of low level GPU programming, so yeah, not an afternoon project.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Compact? It depends. Chains of what length would you use? How many chains? What probability will they give you?